# Flutter navigation pop from which screen

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

Is there anyway to check route name of last screen after pop? When application start and land on home screen, there are several widgets like view profile, product carousel and so on.

Scenario: User navigate into product listing page, then detail page, click purchase and perform actions. After user purchased, shows **purchased successful** screen, call `Navigator.of(context).popUntil(routeName)` back to home screen.

What I want to achieve: After land in home screen, programmatically call api to refresh my balance. [Route Observer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html) able to detect navigation back to home screen with `didPopNext()` method. But this is called no matter it pop from which screen. Therefore the api will repeatedly called which is not ideal. How do I know it was pop from **purchased successful** screen instead of **product listing** screen?

Grateful on any helps and hints!

Answer (score 0):

If you where using `pop()` then you have an option to return some data to previous route but since you are using `popUntil()` you won't be able to do this. So I think you should clear every route and push home route again from purchased successful page using either [pushAndRemoveUntil()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html) or [pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html). That means you can now pass an argument to home screen by which you can decide whether to call the API or not.

```
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      '/',
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
      arguments: []
    );
```

Another option would be to figure out a way to return data using `popUntil()`, Something like [this](https://medium.com/@hungregistermail/flutter-popuntil-with-return-data-ece825aedbd0), maybe?